# Android上でユーザーの入力からCとC++を実行する

Tags: android, c++, c

Android上でユーザーの入力からC/C++を実行することはできるのでしょうか?

EditText上の入力を受け取ってコンパイル、リンクして実行結果を表示するアプリを作りたいと考えているのですが、そもそもAndroid上でユーザーの入力から、C/C++をコンパイルして動かすことは可能なのでしょうか?

Comment: 参考までに、使用したことはないのですがこんなアプリがあります。 - [AIDE- IDE for Android Java C++](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=ja)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android上でユーザーの入力、またはテキストファイルをソースコードとして、C/C++を解釈して実行させるということは可能です。

ただし、コンパイルに関して、どこまでやるのかは問題です。もし.exeにしたいのであれば大変です。
本格的なC/C++開発環境を作るとか、スピードが要求されるタスクをこなすので無ければ、多くのケース（例えばプログラミング言語の学習用アプリなど）でC/C++のインタプリタを作製した方が良い結果が得られると思います。

参考までに、私はこれまでにAndroid上で動く独自のインタプリタ型言語を作っていますが、高度なリアルタイム処理を行わないのであれば、Javaで作ったインタプリタで十分な速度（ゲーム等以外のアプリを作るなら体感速度では気にならないレベル。ただし、ソースコードを効率良く変換しながら実行する必要はある）が出ています。

Comment: gccやclangのandroidで動作するツールチェインを作成してアプリ内に埋め込むことは可能ですか

Comment: 私はやったことないですが、gccはいけると思います。以下のアプリのように作製されている方がいらっしゃるので。https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.n0n3m4.gcc4droid。